# MetadataException - Unable to load the specified metadata resource?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a solution with two relevant projects. The first builds *My.exe*, and the second builds a class library *MyModel.dll* that contains only my EF model.

I'm getting a `MetadataException` in my Model's VS-generated `ObjectContext` ctor. I've read through [Troubleshooting Entity Framework Connection Strings](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/), but I still haven't been able to narrow down my problem.

The offending constructor code:

```
public MyEntities() :
    base(@"name=MyEntities", "MyEntities") // MetadataException here
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

[Metadata Artifact Processing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982042.aspx) is set to `EmbedInOutputAssembly`. When I open *MyModel.dll* in Reflector, I see:

- DataAccessLayer.MyModel.csdl
- DataAccessLayer.MyModel.msl
- DataAccessLayer.MyModel.ssdl

I've tried setting [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983962%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for my *app.config* to `None` and `Content`, and neither makes a difference. The config file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=
            res://*/DataAccessLayer.MyModel.csdl|
            res://*/DataAccessLayer.MyModel.ssdl|
            res://*/DataAccessLayer.MyModel.msl;
            provider=Devart.Data.PostgreSql;
            provider connection string=&quot;
                User Id=MY_USER;
                Password=MY_PASS;
                Host=127.0.0.1;
                Database=MY_DB;
                Persist Security Info=True&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I've tried replacing the resource prefix `res://*/` with both `res://MyModel.dll/` and `res://MyModel/`, leaving the rest intact (because it matches the resources in *MyModel.dll*), but neither solved the problem. My class library is [strong-named](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227566%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Both my executable and class library projects contain references to `System.Data.Entity` and `Devart.Data.PostgreSql`, and *My.dll* is being built to the same location as *My.exe*.

Comment: Look at your assembly with reflector and make sure the names match and that is is actually embedded as a resource. Also the connection needs to be in the calling assemblies app.config or web.confg.

Comment: Are you positive that `MyModel.dll` is even loaded at this time? A hard-wired reference to the assembly in the `res://` URIs may be a better idea than `*`.

Comment: * searches the current assembly for the embedded resource I think. However he still needs to have the connection string in the app.config or web.config of the calling project / exe whatever :) I had this same issue, spent several hours on it.

Comment: The *app.config* file belongs to the project for *My.exe*, and I've tried the hard-wired reference `res://MyModel.dll`. The project for *My.exe* also contains a reference to the `MyModel` project; doesn't this mean `MyModel.dll` should already be loaded?

Comment: I only use one param in my ctor base("name=MyEntities") where Myentities is the exact name of the EF connection string in the app.config or web.config

Comment: Also, everything in this question is copy-pasted and is **exactly** as it exists in my project, except that all occurences of the actual project name have been replaced by "My" in this post. (From my post you can see the resource names I have identified with Reflector are identical to the resource names specified in the connection string.)

Comment: First off you would never refrence the .dll just the assembly name. And no it may not alwyas be loaded.

Comment: @Crazy, as seen in my post, I tried both the full DLL filename and the Assembly name. (Craig's guide shows use of the full filename.) I am trying your suggestion of one param in the ctor base now.

Comment: Mine looks like this: metadata=res:// AssemblyName/EmbeddedResourceName.csdl I am also using a context factory to deal with good ol DbContext

Comment: unless you name your assemblies name.dll.dll then that most likely will not work using the .dll

Comment: I tried making the ctor `public MyEntities() : base(@"name=MyEntities")` and the app.config `connectionString="res://MyModel/DataAccessLayer.MyModel.csdl|..."`, with the same results.

Comment: throw a breakpoint on your context then look through the stack and see what database it is trying to connect to if any

Comment: I am assuming your class is derived from  DbContext? I only sawy the constructor

Comment: The class derives from ObjectContext, and I wasn't able to find much by breaking before the base ctor and looking through the stack. I did write a test function to list loaded assemblies in AppDomain, and `MyModel` is definitely loaded before the base ctor is called.

Comment: Also since the model ctor exists in *MyModel.dll*, does that mean *app.config* should belong to the MyModel project instead of the executable project? I'm unclear on what "calling assembly" refers to -- the assembly calling the Model ctor, or the assembly calling the base ctor?

Comment: The app.config will belong to My.exe. When your project builds, VS will copy it to \bin\My.exe.config. That is what will be used at runtime. The app.config in MyModel.dll's project is used only at desitn time. Note that I have an example app which uses a model in a separate assembly here: http://halfpipe.codeplex.com/

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Entity Framework? I ask becasue your class should be derrived from DbContext not Object Context. EF 4.x they made a bunch of changes like the way context is handled. Craig is correct on the config being used at design time for the project that the model is located in. That is how you do things like update model from database etc.. However the connection string is used at runtime when calling you assembly from the project refrencing it, such as a Web Application.

Comment: You can use either `DbContext` or `ObjectContext` in EF 4.1. They're both supported, and they do different things.

Comment: Well, my config **does** belong to *My.exe* and it is being correctly copied to *\bin\My.exe.config*. I'm using EF 4.0, but it worked up until recently. Also, I really don't want to make the move to 4.1 [yet] and and/or convert to DbContext unless it may potentially solve my problem.

Comment: There are some capabilities that ObjectContext can provide that DbContext doesn't; however our friend here can't even get a connection working which is why I suggested moving to EF 4.1 which in my opinion and many others is much easier for beginners to work with. Not to mention the fact that Vis Studio has some nice T4 temps built in for object generation and such. Oh and it generates your DbContext class for you. Bonus!

Comment: My `ObjectContext` derived class was also VS-generated, but I'll give EF 4.1 a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [stepped into .NET source code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.asps), and by examining the arguments & local variables of internal EF calls, found the resource assembly name was still set to `*`.

It turns out a bug in my application code set the model's default connection string *before* calling the `ObjectContext` ctor. It was pulled from a *Settings.settings* file, which hadn't been recently sync'd with the latest, correct *app.config*.

Some reflections on our discussion in the comments:

- The correct assembly name in app.config is `MyModel` rather than `MyModel.dll` (as shown in Craig's article.) Using `MyModel.dll` produces an exception in the EF code.
- Calling the ctor as `base(@"name=MyEntities")` instead of `base(@"name=MyEntities", "MyEntities")` actually produced a new exception in `ObjectContext.GetEntitySetName()`

I updated *Settings.settings* to be in sync with *app.config*, and everything is now working.